# How can I extract least correlated columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I wanted to extract least correlated columns.
Excel example is below:

[image]

The data is read into a list.
copy and paste is possible in your machine.

```
data = [[1.0, 0.753392, 3.0, 0.725201], [2.0, 0.041109837, 6.0, 0.062877178], [3.0, 0.423832988, 9.0, 0.866027735], [4.0, 0.434915355, 12.0, 0.192467473], [5.0, 0.654428813, 15.0, 0.108341448], [6.0, 0.324773769, 18.0, 0.844229809], [7.0, 0.967524725, 21.0, 0.934810338], [8.0, 0.793547241, 24.0, 0.990572248], [9.0, 0.741736506, 27.0, 0.74011758], [10.0, 0.187684226, 30.0, 0.41631089], [11.0, 0.206195617, 33.0, 0.819677047], [12.0, 0.025064815, 36.0, 0.688291108], [13.0, 0.534330027, 39.0, 0.032694883], [14.0, 0.018739144, 42.0, 0.354950289], [15.0, 0.091988505, 45.0, 0.491944161], [16.0, 0.030296596, 48.0, 0.269117609], [17.0, 0.498798595, 51.0, 0.524733097], [18.0, 0.099476344, 54.0, 0.845788803], [19.0, 0.070866294, 57.0, 0.997247157], [20.0, 0.464518871, 60.0, 0.172750938], [21.0, 0.733827466, 63.0, 0.822552104], [22.0, 0.354165581, 66.0, 0.214911818]]


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print df

       0         1     2         3
0    2.0  0.041110   6.0  0.062877
1    3.0  0.423833   9.0  0.866028
2    4.0  0.434915  12.0  0.192467
3    5.0  0.654429  15.0  0.108341
4    6.0  0.324774  18.0  0.844230
5    7.0  0.967525  21.0  0.934810
6    8.0  0.793547  24.0  0.990572
7    9.0  0.741737  27.0  0.740118
8   10.0  0.187684  30.0  0.416311
9   11.0  0.206196  33.0  0.819677
10  12.0  0.025065  36.0  0.688291
11  13.0  0.534330  39.0  0.032695
12  14.0  0.018739  42.0  0.354950
13  15.0  0.091989  45.0  0.491944
14  16.0  0.030297  48.0  0.269118
15  17.0  0.498799  51.0  0.524733
16  18.0  0.099476  54.0  0.845789
17  19.0  0.070866  57.0  0.997247
18  20.0  0.464519  60.0  0.172751
19  21.0  0.733827  63.0  0.822552
20  22.0  0.354166  66.0  0.214912


r2 = df.corr()**2

print r2

          0         1         2         3
0  1.000000  0.033327  1.000000  0.000218
1  0.033327  1.000000  0.033327  0.037813
2  1.000000  0.033327  1.000000  0.000218
3  0.000218  0.037813  0.000218  1.000000

result = np.argwhere(np.triu(np.abs(r2.values) <= 0.047)) 

print result
[[0 3]
 [2 3]]
```

But, not expected result, [0,1,3].

Any best practice to do this kind of problem is welcomed.

edit:
expected result, least correlated data with 3 columns (A,B,and D)

```
1   0.753391901 0.725201405
2   0.041109837 0.062877178
3   0.423832988 0.866027735
4   0.434915355 0.192467473
5   0.654428813 0.108341448
6   0.324773769 0.844229809
7   0.967524725 0.934810338
8   0.793547241 0.990572248
9   0.741736506 0.74011758
10  0.187684226 0.41631089
11  0.206195617 0.819677047
12  0.025064815 0.688291108
13  0.534330027 0.032694883
14  0.018739144 0.354950289
15  0.091988505 0.491944161
16  0.030296596 0.269117609
17  0.498798595 0.524733097
18  0.099476344 0.845788803
19  0.070866294 0.997247157
20  0.464518871 0.172750938
21  0.733827466 0.822552104
22  0.354165581 0.214911818
```

Comment: I just realized your data in Excel and the data in Pandas are totally different, too. That explains why the R^2 values are different.

Comment: yes, corrected now, both giving same

Answer (score 1):

Since you have multiple pairs, this is the best way, I think:

```
rs = r2.stack()
rs_min = rs[rs <= rs.min() + 1e-4] # I added some tolerance here
cols = rs_min.index.values
```

With your data, this gives me

```
>>> rs_min.index.values
array([(0, 3), (2, 3), (3, 0), (3, 2)], dtype=object)
```

If you want a flattened list of unique values, you can transform the array:

```
vals = list(set(item[1] for item in vals))
```

(you can use `item[0]` or `item[1]`, because the pairs are symmetric anyway) 
which gives

```
>>> list(set(item[1] for item in vals))
[0, 2, 3]
```

Based on your tables, note that Excel and Pandas do give different results for the correlation. This code assumes  Pandas gives the correct results.

EDIT:

If you want to get your original results data back, then you can do

```
print(data[:, vals])
```

That should give you your result.

Comment: Can you clarify? I thought you wanted the column names (which were in r2 as numbers) which had the lowest r^2 values. What do you mean by "columnar data"?

Comment: Oh, so you also want to get the lowest values of R^2, in addition to the columns [0,2,3]?

Comment: Column 0 is actually your *index*, that's why. Let me fix that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174931/discussion-between-irene-and-brute).

Comment: Okay I edited my answer above. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: ummm, that's answer,

Comment: I still don't understand what you want. `data[:, vals]` gives you the data for the columns with the least correlation (which, with the data you gave me, are pairs 0-3, 2-3 -- you can check the r^2 table that you generated).

Comment: Great! If my answer helped you, I'd appreciate it if you could accept my answer. Thanks!